# How to solve "cannot index into a value of type `&dyn Trait`"

Tags: rust

I am trying to expose a Vector with a limited interface so it later on may be replaced by something else.
Thus I have a trait `Vectorish`, which defines `index`.

If I however then try to call `v[0] =` I get the error message:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `&dyn Vectorish`
```

See the playground that illustrates that:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=54acc9bd2f60844e3eedf3b6e4b18401

Comment: Indexing with the `[]`-notation is syntax sugar for the trait [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html), `Vectorish` doesn't impement or require it. Rust doesn't have duck-typing that allows similar behaviour in other languages.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3b3f4b1f2bbc65194c576cdd71212e2).

Comment: Thx. Then the error message is at least not as great as it could. Should probably mention, that Vectorish does not implement Index trait.

Comment: on my experience, abstract a collection is often a bad/useless idea.

Comment: @Stargateur In my particular case everything is living in one crate, so you are probably right that it would have had limited usefulness.